# Playing .rm video files in flash

Tags: flash

I know .flv video files can be played in flash. I wanted to know if I can play .rm video files?

For example this: http://mfile.akamai.com/7870/rm/mitstorage.download.akamai.com/7870/11/11.309/s06/lecturenotes/ocw-11.309j-06mar2006-56k.rm

Vladimir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.

These codecs are supported:
[List of codecs supported by Adobe Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can play realmedia files in Flash.